# android gradle file having duplicate classes

Tags: java, opencv, build.gradle, javacv

I am trying to add javacv to my build.gradle however it already has opencv imbedded in the sdk(this is for a robitics competition).

> Duplicate class org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback found in modules jetified-opencv-4.7.0-1.5.9 (org.bytedeco:opencv:4.7.0-1.5.9) and jetified-opencv-repackaged-bundled-dylibs-4.7.0-A-runtime (org.openftc:opencv-repackaged-bundled-dylibs:4.7.0-A)

Note: i tried looking at other questions but couldn't find an answer to this. If there is a post I apologize I missed it.

```
Here is the gradle script:
implementation(group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.5.9') {
exclude group: 'org.opencv', module: 'android'
}
```

I cannot show that of the opencv implementation as I couldn't access that file. Is there a way to exclude it properly? Here is an example of the error:

Thank you!

Here is the entire log:
https://pastebin.com/KAddmZnX

Comment: You should be able to use their dependencies without adding anything of your own. What happens if you try to do that? I think `exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'opencv-platform'` should work.